# how to open a process in a remote server using apache telnet

Tags: java, unix, process, telnet

i encountered a problem using the apache commons-net telnet api, and hope you can help me with it.

i am connecting to a remote unix server via telnet and running a script , that at some point run an .sh file. that file open a server that needs to continue running even after the telnet connection to the client is closed. the problem is that when i close the client connection the process stops. i think that when the connection is lost there is no reference to the running process and the os is killing it but im not sure.
if that is the case i understand that if a could open the server process as a deamon process the problem will be resolve.
maybe there are other ways to do it...

can someone help me to solve this thing?
thank
moshe ben noun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `nohup` and running the process in the background using `&` should do what you are looking for.

http://www.livefirelabs.com/unix_tip_trick_shell_script/june_2003/06022003.htm